# Dark spot appearing on the Screen , MacBook Pro 13

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, screen

When screen brightness is low I get this dark spot in my screen. Is this something serious ?

[image: Dark spot on the MacBook screen]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a dead backlight LED.

If your computer is still under AppleCare I would suggest to bring it to an Apple Store or to an Apple Premium Reseller.